# Export multiple results to sequentially named Excel sheets

Tags: export, mapthread

When, I want to export a lot of my results to excel, how can I make sure that the Sheet name is also listed according to the results?

For example, There is a following the result.

```
result[1] = {{a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}}
result[2] = {{a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}}
result[3] = {{a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}}
result[4] = {{a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}}
・・・
result[100] = {{a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}}
```

If I don't care about the sheet name, then the output formula would look like this:

```
answer = Table[result[i], {i, n}]
Export["newfiles.xlsx", answer, "XLSX"]
```

However, I want the names of the output Excel sheets to be `result1` and `result2` ... instead of the default `sheet1` and `sheet2` ... respectively.

```
Export["newfile.xlsx",{"result 1" -> result[1],"result 2" -> result[2],"result 3" -> result[3]}......."result 100" -> result[100], "XLSX"]
```

Instead of doing this manually, how can it be automated?

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
nres = 4;
result[1] = {{a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}}; 
result[2] = {{d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}, {m, n, o}, {p, q, r}}; 
result[3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {a, b, c}}; 
result[4] = {{11, 22, 33}, {44, 55, 66}, {77, 88, 99}};

names = "result" <> IntegerString[#, 10, 3] & /@ Range[nres];

res = MapThread[Rule[#1, #2] &, { names, result[#] & /@ Range[nres]}];

Export["C:/test2.xls", res, "XLS"];
```

Answer (score 1):

A little code golf...

```
(*example copied from Syed*) 
result[1] = {{a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}}; 
result[2] = {{d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}, {m, n, o}, {p, q, r}}; 
result[3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {a, b, c}}; 
result[4] = {{11, 22, 33}, {44, 55, 66}, {77, 88, 99}};

(* proposed solution *)

output[data_, i_] := With[
  {name = StringTemplate["result``"]@IntegerString[First@i, 10, 3]},
  Rule[name, data]]

With[
 {sheets = MapIndexed[output, Values@DownValues[result]]},
 Export["test2.xlsx", sheets]]
```

Benefits:

- No new symbols are permanently defined (except for an output function;
- no need to predefine the number number of symbols
- no need to specify export as "XLSX", as this is inferred from the filename

Comments:

- You are making your life hard with `result[1]`, etc. instead of just making these lists; the `Values@DownValues[result]` essentially does this conversion (assuming these have sequential values)
- If you were a fan of one-liners, you could get rid of the `With[]` construct and just put the code in place, but I find it is a bit clearer to read this way